# words to describe the sound bombing makes?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I report in English in a conflict zone. I often need to describe the sound bombing and airstrikes make when slammed into their target, mainly nearby. The only word I use in such situation is "explosion" or "blast" but I do need a variety of options to choose from. Is there any other word, whether it's verbs, nouns, adjectives, that can describe the above mentioned situation?

Comment: Different types of bombs make different sounds whilst they travel to their target and when they explode: it also depends on how far away you are. If you want the right words to use about a particular conflict, it is best to read reports from that conflict.

Comment: Thanks JavaLatte for your reply. Actually, reports from that conflict area are usually hard news reports that don't get into details or add color to the reporting.

Answer (score 1):

"Explosion" and "Blast" 100% work in this situation.

> The explosion sound made from the bomb was extremely loud.
>
> The blast from the bomb was extremely loud.

If these words become too repetitive I suggest using onomatopoeias.

Onomatopoeias are words that express a sound and could be used as an interjection at the beginning of the sentence.

> Boom! The bomb went off after the minute was up.

The "boom" at the beginning of the sentence could be replaced by a variety of different onomatopoeias. Such as "boosh", "bam".

For further list of these words see:
[List of Onomatopoeias](http://www.onomatopoeialist.com)